# About "Node,File,Directory,Link" and "Visitor"

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have a question about the "head file" in c++,now I have a superclass "Node" and three subclass "File,Directory,File"

```
class Node {
public:
    //declare common interface here
    void setName(string& name);
    const string getName();
    //  const Protection& getProtection();

    //  void setProtection(const Protection&);
    void setCDate(char* cDate);
    char* getCDate();
    long size();

    void streamIn(istream&);
    void streamOut(ostream&);

    Node* getChild(int index);
    virtual void adopt(Node* child);
    virtual void orphan(Node* child);

    virtual void accept(Visitor&) = 0;
    static void destroy(Node*);
protected:
    Node();
    Node(const Node&);
    virtual ~Node();
    virtual bool isWritable() = 0;
private:
    string name;
    char* cDate;
};
class Directory : public Node {
public:
    Directory();
    Directory(string path);
    //redeclare common interface here
    void setName(string& name);
    string getName();
    void setCDate(char* cDate);
    char* getCDate();
    long size();
    Node* getChild(int index);
    virtual void adopt(Node* child);  //add children
    virtual void orphan(Node* child); //let the subnode be free
    virtual void accept(Visitor&);
private:
    list<Node*> _nodes;     //hold its subnode
    string& name;
    char* cDate;
};
```

The File and Link is the same as the class directory,here is the class visitor:

```
class Visitor{
public:
    virtual ~Visitor() {}
    virtual void visitNode(Node*) = 0;
    virtual void visitFile(File*) = 0;
    virtual void visitDirectory(Directory*) = 0;
    virtual void visitLink(Link*) = 0;
protected:
    Visitor();
    Visitor(const Visitor&);
};
```

each of them are in different head file, I want to know how can I import those head file

Comment: please reformat your question, it lacks clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Visitor you don't need to include the header as the compiler does not need to know the size of the objects.  You can simply forward declare.

```
class Node;
class File;
class Directory;
class Link;

class Visitor{
public:
    virtual ~Visitor() {}
    virtual void visitNode(Node*) = 0;
    virtual void visitFile(File*) = 0;
    virtual void visitDirectory(Directory*) = 0;
    virtual void visitLink(Link*) = 0;
protected:
    Visitor();
    Visitor(const Visitor&);
};
```

However the compiler will need to know the size for the implementation but you can include them in your cpp file.

Edit:
For the case of your `accept(Vistor&)` functions then that is pretty simple too.  In your header files forward declare the Visitor class in the headers of `File`, `Directory`, and `Link`.  Then in the implementation `#include` the header of Visitor.

Also thinking about it I think you could do away with `visitX` functions as `File`, `Directory` and `Link` are all types of `Node` and don't need to be explicity visited.

Comment: Thank you, this may be a solution, and I have tried it, if you can tell me how to modify the accept(Visitor&), that would be better:

Answer (score 0):

Generally if you have two header files such as 1.h and 2.h with both of them in the same folder

"header file 1.h"

```
class A {..}
```

"header file 2.h"

```
class B {..}
```

and if you want to use class A in 2.h, then add the following lines in 2.h,

```
#include "./1.h"   // Change the path if the header is some other directory
```

so your 2.h file would become,

```
#include "./1.h"
class B {..}
```

Comment: Do you mean that the question is my project's path? I think this may not be main reason, because all of them are in my header folder in my vc++ 6.0, you can either download my source code in http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1088339377&uk=1041919606,I really hope you can help me to solve this problem,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are named: directory.h, file.h, link.h, visitor.h, then you must include directory.h at the beginning of file.h and link.h files:

```
#include "directory.h"
```

as in these files class Node defined in directory.h is used. In visitor.h likewise you must include all the files where the classes used in Visitor definition are defined:

```
#include "directory.h"  
#include "file.h"  
#include "link.h"
```

Comment: I think your "directory.h" is my "Node.h",I tried to do that, however, my compiler always tell me "error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Visitor'", what I use now is vc++ 6.0,you can download my code in http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1088339377&uk=1041919606